# separate the system & hardware clock in linux

Tags: linux, rhel, clock

I want to separate the system clock from the hardware clock which I synchronize first. But now I want to change both: hardware clock with the UTC time & system with the GPS time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but whatever you're trying to do will probably involve the [`hwclock`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock) command. This is the command to read or set the harwdare clock. The main ways to use it are:

- `hwclock --systohc`: set the hardware clock to the system time
- `hwclock --hctosys`: set the system time to the hardware clock
- `hwclock --set --date='…'`: set the hardware clock to a particular time

Beware of timezones: if you keep your hardware clock in UTC (recommended), pass the `--utc` option to `hwclock`.